# how do you access a method from another class / thread without instantiation, static variables or passing references?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates, instantiation

After redesigning my application somewhat to incorporate a more flexible design, i'm running into some troubles with accessing a method located on the MAINFORM, from another class which runs from within a thread. below are some code snippets to show what i'm trying to do:

MAIN FORM:

```
public void setAlarmColour(byte[] result, int buttonNumber)
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                //txtOutput1.Text = (result[4] == 0x00 ? "HIGH" : "LOW"); // runs on UI thread

                if (result[4] == 0x00)
                {
                    this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Controls["btn" + buttonNumber].BackColor = Color.Red;
                }


            });

        }


    }
```

CLASS A:

```
public void connect(IDeviceInterface device)
    {
        //send data
        byte[] bData = new byte[71];
        bData[0] = 240;
        bData[1] = 240;
        bData[2] = 0;
        bData[3] = 1;
        bData[68] = 240;
        bData[69] = 240;
        bData[70] = this.CalculateCheckSum(bData);


        try
        {

            byte[] result = this.SendCommandResult(device.deviceIPAddress, device.devicePort, bData, 72);
            //send byte + buttonNumber to setAlarmColour on main thread here.

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

now, to answer a few questions you might be thinking to ask, why do i not want to do some of the things explained in the title.

- the device class which holds the connect() method runs in a thread. this is because i have multiple of these going on, one for each device i'm trying to monitor, for exampl.
- i can't instantiate a new form as i need to update the current one, therefore mainForm main = new mainForm() isn't an option
- using static on my method in the main form causes issues with accessing the form controls it's trying to change in the first place, mainly at the "this.controls[]" part. although if anyonyone has a workaround for this, i'm open to ideas
- i don't want to pass a reference to the main form IF POSSIBLE as it could get messy handing this around everywhere, and as far as i'm aware it's considered bad practise, especially as projects increase in size. i have done this on an earlier version and i had to pass this reference about 3/4 times before i even got to where i needed to go.

is there a way i could do this by using delegates / events or such? i've tried reading about doing this but some of it seems confusing and i'm not sure what's going where. Also, like i said, i'm open to new ideas so if you can show me a way of using the options i ruled out in an efficient way then i'm open minded.

Does anyone have any idea how i can access this method in the main form from class A?
p.s. if anyone needs additional information, simply ask.

edit 1: 
with ideas from jon skeet, i've decided to try and implement events to handle this problem. i'm running into some problems though...

the only time my form knows about the class is when it dynamically creates them based on how many entries / instances of class A i'm creating.
in my class A, i have created:

```
 public event EventHandler setAlarmColour = delegate { };
```

then i fire the event in the same class as such:

```
 this.setAlarmColour(this, new EventArgs());
```

and subscribe to the event during the dynamic creation of the class, as such:

```
 bfdevice.setAlarmColourDelegate += new EventHandler(setAlarmColour);
```

where bfdevice = class A and setAlarmColourDelegate is the event handler, and setAlarmColour is my method in mainform i'm trying to access,
but i need to pass parameters through to

```
 EventHandler(setAlarmColour)
```

namely "byte[]result, int buttonNumber"
as currently i'm getting "No overload for "setAlarmColour" matches delegate "System.EventHandler"
any ideas?

the problem here is that the parameters i need to send to setAlarmColour are only known in class A, which isn't where i'm subscribing to the event. therefore i cannot do setAlarmColour(result, buttonNumber) as mainform has no reference to these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `ClassA` could expose a `CommandReceived` event. The form would then subscribe to that event for each instance of `ClassA`. This is *really* passing a reference to `ClassA`, within the delegate event handler, but it's all hidden.

Fundamentally, each instance of `ClassA` has to get back to the instance of the form *somehow*. I would strongly advise you *not* to do this via a static variable, which would introduce tight coupling and reduce testability.

If you don't like the event idea, you'll have to pass the reference to `ClassA` some other way - e.g. in the constructor. In this case you'd probably introduce an interface between the two - `ClassA`'s constructor would have a parameter of the interface type, and your form would implement the interface. That would loosen the coupling between the two.

Comment: could you perhaps give example of the first paragraphs worth of your answer? i think this suits my program best as it doesn't lead to lost flexibility and i don't end up cluttered in passing references around. cheers in advance.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter: Well which bit would you have trouble with? How much do you know about events, and how to declare them, and how to implement them?

Comment: i know a little about them, but i wouldn't say i could build one from scratch straight off the bat. there's 3 parts to them, right? looking online, i find it hard to think about them in the context of solving my problem.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter: You can probably use a generic delegate - e.g. `EventHandler<T>` for the delegate part. Then you should just be able to declare a field-like event in `ClassA` and subscribe to it from your form. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx for more details.

Comment: it's my method in class A that attempts to call the method in mainForm, would my form method still be the one subscribing, or the other way around? i'm hoping that the setAlarmColour method can be used by each plug in class like class A, so would i have to sub each one of these?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter: Your form would subscribe to the event, and ClassA would raise the event. It's unclear what you really mean about your plugin architecture, I'm afraid.

Comment: just reading through the article you linked. trying to get my head around it and hopefully solve my problem. Thanks for all your help though!

Comment: i'm still a tad stuck on this. i'm not sure how to create / raise an event between the classes without one of them creating an instance of another..perhaps i'm just confusing myself now and this isn't making sense to either of us..

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter: The form will need to know about the instance of `ClassA` it needs to subscribe to, certainly. Fundamentally unless you go down the dirty static route (don't! global state sucks!) you need *one* of the instances to know about the other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11879/discussion-between-shane-shamus-coulter-and-jon-skeet)